# AWS glue endpoint and port forwarding and spark program throws error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have been struggling to find the solution for the issue running spark program in zeppelin notebook. Not sure what going wrong

I am using zeppelin zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all
I have created AWS glue endpoint and port forwarding.

Followed these links nothing helped me
https://gist.github.com/codspire/7b0955b9e67fe73f6118dad9539cbaa2
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html

When i run piece of spark code in http://localhost:8080/

```
%pyspark
a=5*4
print("value = %i" % (a))
sc.version
```

Getting the following error

> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException   at
> org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
> at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
> at
> org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
> at
> org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
> at
> org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
> at
> org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:266)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:250)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:373)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:406)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)  at
> org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:329)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
> Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown
> Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
> Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
> Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating your endpoint you need to create it with the Glue version compatible to your Zeppelin. In your case (**Zeppelin 0.7.3**) you need the **Glue Version 0.9**.